# Как передать ссылку через sendMessage (telegram api)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vkontakte-api, api

Пытаюсь передать ссылку через бота в канал 
`https://api.telegram.org/bot<API-TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=-xxxxxxxxxxx&text=https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=Друга Ріка - Впусти мене&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8` 
При передачи сообщения, ссылка приходит, но вот в таком виде: 
`https://www.google.com/search?client=opera`

ссылку формирую так

```
methods: {
            send() {
                this.resultLink = "https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=" + this.idMessage + "&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8"                   
                axios
                    .get("https://api.telegram.org/bot<API-TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=-xxxxxxxxxxxx&text=" + this.resultLink)
                    .then(resp => {
                        this.getInfos = resp.data.result
                    });
            }
```

Попробовал несколько вариантов на подобии, Html тегов, Markdown (), но нечего не помогло
Через fiddler ссылка выглядит так: 
 
`https://api.telegram.org/bot<API-TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=-xxxxxxxxxxxx&text=https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%20%D0%A0%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%20-%20%D0%92%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8`
 
И если её отдельно скопировать, то она работает. 
 
 `https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%20%D0%A0%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%20-%20%D0%92%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, проблема в количестве символов. При передачи ссылки не превышающей ограничение, все отрабатывает нормально. Правда как обойти эту проблему, решения пока не нашёл(

Answer (score 0):

попробуй линк завернуть в

```
this.resultLink = "<a href=\"https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=" + this.idMessage + "&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8\""> click </a>

get("https://api.telegram.org/bot<API-TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=-xxxxxxxxxxxx&text=" + this.resultLink + "&parse_mode=\"HTML\"")
```

и добавить аргумент parse_mode='HTML'

Comment: я не подключал api. в переложение, запрос формирую по ссылке, как видно в примере. Как добавить аргумент ` parse_mode='HTML'` в тело запроса?

Comment: переписал, попробуй )

Comment: Не, не сработало (.

Answer (score 0):

чтоб обойти проблему длинной ссылки можно сократить ее через сервисы различные, например - кликер от яндекса

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]